# How do I sort the bars when the barchart represents the number of occurances?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I draw a barchart in R:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=rating, fill=rating)) +
geom_bar(stat="count") +
ggtitle("Rating in stories")+
coord_flip()+
xlab("rating")+
ylab("number of stories")+
theme(legend.position="none")
```

The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygzFj.png).
The bars represent the amount of times the specific value (M, T, K or K+) occurs in the rating variable.
How do I sort the bars decreasingly?

Comment: Glad that you found the answer that you were looking for. However, it is usually better if you could provide us some data to work with in a reproducible format. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Providing solutions just looking at the code without data is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found what I was looking for. I needed to use fct_rev(fct_infreq()) on the variable.

```
ggplot(data, aes(forcats::fct_rev(fct_infreq(rating)), fill=rating)) +
geom_bar(stat = "count") +
ggtitle("Rating in stories")+
coord_flip()+
xlab("rating")+
ylab("number of stories")+
theme(legend.position="none")
```